# Conditional count in dataframe across columns time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I conditionally count in each row the number of instances where theres a value in the previous date then decrease to 0 in the next date?

df:

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr
A   1   2   3   0
B   0   0   0   0
C   1   0   2   0
D   0   0   0   1
```

want to get: df_to_zero_count

```
    Count
A   1
B   0
C   2
D   0
```

I've tried some combination of apply and iterating through columns but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: wondering if there is a python way to achieve this instead of transposing then iterating on the date rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
((df.diff(axis=1) < 0) & (df == 0)).sum(axis=1)
```

You can check where the differential over the rows is smaller than 0 (that indicates a decrease) and the value of the cells is 0 too.

output:

```
((df.diff(axis=1) < 0) & (df == 0)).sum(axis=1)

0    1
1    0
2    2
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df_to_zero_count = (df.T.eq(0) & df.T.shift(fill_value=0).ne(0)).sum().to_frame(name='Count')
```

Result:

```
print(df_to_zero_count)


   Count
A      1
B      0
C      2
D      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df.shift(axis=1).fillna(0)
df["count"] = ((df == 0) & (x != 0)).sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  count
A    1    2    3    0      1
B    0    0    0    0      0
C    1    0    2    0      2
D    0    0    0    1      0
```